# Why Ext.grid.GridPanel is slow?

Tags: extjs, extjs4, extjs3

> I'm using Ext.grid.GridPanel,version ExtJs3.4. It takes minimum 6
>   to 7 seconds to load 1000 records into grid. 
>   My java part gives the result in less than 1 second but rendering
>   takes 6 to 7 seconds. 
>       What could be the problem? 
>       what could be possible solution to increase the performance?
>       Here is my code.

```
var grid = new Ext.grid.GridPanel({
                title:gridtitle,
                border: false,
                height: getGridHeight(),
                autoScroll:true,
                store: store,
                id:'grid',
                colModel: createColModel(gridnoofcols),
                loadMask: true,
                view: new Ext.grid.GroupingView({
                    autoFill:true,
                    groupTextTpl: getGroupConfig(),
                    emptyText: emptytext,deferEmptyText: false
                }),
                listeners: {
                    render : function(grid){
                      grid.store.on('load', function(store, records, options){
                        grid.getSelectionModel().selectFirstRow();       
                      });                      
                    }
                   },
                plugins: [filters],        
                bbar: new Ext.Toolbar({
                })
    });

Following are the Column model

var createColModel = function (finish, start) {
    var columns = [
        new Ext.grid.RowNumberer({
            header: "<span style=font-weight:bold;><%=SLNO%></span>",
            width: 50
        }), {
            dataIndex: 'slnoIndex',
            hidden: true,
            header: "<span style=font-weight:bold;><%=SLNO%></span>",
            filter: {
                type: 'numeric'
            }
        }, <%=liveVisionColumns.getGridHeaderBuffer(processID,language,checkFDAS).toString()%>
    ];
    return new Ext.grid.ColumnModel({
        columns: columns.slice(start || 0, finish),
        defaults: {
            sortable: true
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: Why haven't you paginated the query to populate the grid?
Extjs gridpanel work well with pagination

Comment: I'll try to paginated........ Actually Ext.ux.grid.livegrid.GridPanel is faster than GridPanel but it has some problems like filters, grid is automatically loading if we click on header but thanks for your valuable comment.

Comment: Do you have any idea about livegrid filters? Filter is not working for extjs3.4 livegrid?

Answer (score 1):

It might be slow because of number of records and grouping view. However, 6-7 seconds are still too much. The column model is probably the problem. Number of columns and renderers can really slow extjs grids. Try to avoid column renderers.
Could you please share the column model ?

Comment: I have edited my post. Kindly looking into it...Please lemme know the problems

Comment: I haven't used column renderers but yeah my header is dynamic. Does it make any difference?

Comment: No it does not. But you still didnt show the result of "liveVisionColumns.getGridHeaderBuffer". And finally the best you can do, is profiling your grid. Override extjs grid_panel to put "console.log" somewhere inside and see what takes so long.
Note: Can you also try without grouping view and see the result?

Comment: liveVisionColumns.getGridHeaderBuffer

header: '<span style=font-weight:bold;>Vehicle No</span>', 
dataIndex: 'vehiclenoindex',
width:100,
filter: {
 type:'string'
}
},

Comment: It looks simple. As i said, you should profile your grid. I did such things so many times in my 8+ years experience of extjs and solved many problems :) Just dig into grid panel source code, copy it to your project, change the  class name, add console.log to rendering methods, and use it instead of original component.

Comment: I'm new to extjs. Could you please lemme know " what is profiling of grid " ?